# Segmentation fault occurs with GetStringUTFChars JNI method in Android environment

Tags: android, gdb, java-native-interface

I have a class with a JNI function call like the following:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_sensoft_ssiutils_File_load(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject  obj,
        jstring base_name) {

    ...
    const char* text_input = env->GetStringUTFChars(base_name, nullptr);    
    ...
}
```

That I've built to run on the Android x86 platform using the Android NDK on Windows. In my android application, I use **System.loadLibrary** to load the so file and I'm able to debug and step into the function via gdb when I run this in an emulator running gdbserver, however the **GetStringUTFChars** function always causes a SEGFAULT:

**Thread 1 "cations.dt1demo" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.**

I've also tried some suggestions on setting the SIGSEGV handle to nopass, noprint and nostopin the gdb, but it just stalls the program.

Comment: What makes you think the SIGSEGV is intentional?  Surely it is more likely that the SIGSEGV is a result of some error in your program which you should try to resolve?  Setting the signal handler to `nopass` is going to mean that your program never sees the signal, so, if the signal is required for correct operation, then the program will not see it and will not function correctly.  Setting the signal handler to `noprint` / `nostop` means GDB will not stop on the signal, so, if the signal indicates an error, GDB will not stop to allow you to debug the issue.

Comment: Are you checking for pending exceptions or failures of any kind in **all** of your JNI function calls?  What you are seeing is typical behavior when prior failures or pending exceptions are ignored.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tried again with my jni function and removed all other functions calls besides the JNI GetStringUTFChars calls to rule out if my code caused this, but I still get a SIGSEGV signal which still causes a Seg fault on that JNI call